# Can you identify cello and piano piece in last scene of Agatha Christie ABC Murders (v. 2018 John Malkovich)?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I thought I knew my classical music well until I heard this piece in the 2018 BBC/AMAZON PRIME VIDEO production of *Agatha Christie's The ABC Murders* with John Malkovich as Poirot.  It is a cello and piano piece, possibly a Sonata, definitely in the romantic/neo romantic style.  It was played in the very last scene of the drama (3rd episode @53:41). I have tried everything to get the soundtrack list for the whole drama: sent emails to the BBC Productions, Agatha Christie Productions, tweeted the composer of the original soundtrack music (a lady by the name of Isobel Waller-Bridge) and asked for help from our national classical music station in Australia (@abc.classic), but no one bothered to answer!

Please, can you help?

***SPOILER ALERT***

I uploaded to YT the segment where the music is played, https://youtu.be/C-m7Fk6mEfU but it reveals the ending of the whole series so if you have not watched it ....

Thanks a lot

Gareth (madaboutvoice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of the second movement of Franz Schubert's [Piano Trio in E-flat major](https://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Trio_in_E-flat_major%2C_D.929_(Schubert%2C_Franz)) (D.929) arranged for cello and piano (originally for violin, cello and piano).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much PiedPiper!!!.  I knew the tune and am sure I listened to the trio several times in the past.  Before asking, in my mind I was sure it had to be either late Beethoven or Schubert, but what threw me was the absence of any other instruments to make me try to think outside of the the confined cello and piano duo limit I had set for myself. I must admit that lately I have been concentrating my listening on the three B's.  My next project is to go back and listen intently to all of Schubert's chamber works particularly the string quartets Thanks again, now I can sleep easy :) phew!

Comment: Went back and listened to the music in the video, and it seems it is an arrangement for the opening theme of the 2nd movt. that intentionally excludes the violin when the piano repeats the melody played by the cello at the very start.  Live and learn :)   I think I will mark this question answered now.  Cheers!

Comment: @madaboutvoice I didn't listen long enough to enough to realize it's an arrangement. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Schubert, Piano Trio No. 2, Op. 100, D. 929, in E-flat Major 2nd mov.

Answer (score 0):

The Agatha Christie's The ABC Murders Season 1, Episode 1 piano and cello piece is Handel's Sarabande, beautiful.